# How to handle back button in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have an application, the main page contains few functions. To explain in detail - I have save, color palette button in my main page. When any of these buttons are clicked, save pop up or color palette appears. How to handle back button of the device, when color palette or save pop up is opened. When back button is pressed at these scenario it should just make them invisible and stay on the main page. When nothing is being performed in the main page, then it should come out of the app. I tried to make their visibility collapsed on back button press. But it still is coming out of the application.

Please, guide me in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Override [PhoneApplicationPage.OnBackKeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.onbackkeypress%28VS.92%29.aspx) and then set `CancelEventArgs.Cancel` to `true` if you want to stop it from actually going back.

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs args)
{
    if (PanelIsShowing)
    {
        HidePanel();
        args.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already tried this way, but I have a doubt, in this case, the panel will hide and come out of the application. But my requirement is to hide the panel and if there is nothing on the main page working like no pop up, then only it should come out of the application.

Comment: If you do not set `args.Cancel = true` then the back button will behave as it normally does. That is, if you are on the first page of your application, it will exit.

Comment: @Kyberias - I beg to differ. Care to elaborate on why you won't think it works?

Answer (score 0):

The back button behaves as is intended by Microsoft.

If you change its behavior you risk your application not being certified for the Marketplace.

If you want the back button to close the popups, turn the popups into pages so the back button navigates back to the main page..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (_popup.IsOpen)
    {
        _popup.IsOpen= false;
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {
        base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
    }
}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: the `base.OnBackKeyPress(e)` makes sure that normal navigation takes place if you donot have a popup open.